# Product attributes as dropdown menu in WooCommerce with Goya theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I'm new to WordPress and I'm a bit stuck with a WooCommerce website that uses the [Goya theme](https://goya.everthemes.com/). I have added product attributes and product variations for my variable products.

However, the theme displays them as links *(see [the Color and Size selection in  Goya theme](https://goya.everthemes.com/demo-fashion/product/basic-micro-rib-turtleneck/))*.

I would like to display the attributes as a dropdown menu.

How to show variation attributes as dropdown menus for single variable products pages?

Comment: Ask the theme authors as there is surely a setting yo disable that feature. Note that by default woocommerce uses dropdowns. I suppose that this theme use a variation swatches plugin.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks! I suppose I should check the theme files, then? I know that editing the parent theme files is not recommended, though. If I want to make changes to parent theme files, I should copy them to my child theme instead and make changes in the child theme, right? I'll take a look at the Variantion Swatches plugin too

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Also, I noticed this line in my Goya parent theme: `$classes[] = 'et-variation-style-' . goya_meta_config('product','variations_style',true); `. Could this have something to do with product attributes' display?

Comment: Ask theme authors to know how to disable attribute swatches and have instead WooCommerce default feature for variable products. Don't edit the theme files.

Comment: That means that in the theme there are available settings to remove that… So search in your theme settings…